# Transform a curl call to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl command that I know works.  I've tried translating it to python but it raises an error.

Specifically, the response complains that the "model" field hasn't been defined.  What is the appropriate way to define the form data?

curl:

```
curl \
    -F data_file=@my_audio_file.mp3 \
    -F model=en-US \
    -F 'notification=callback' \
    -F 'callback=http://your_url.com/transcript_callback'
    "https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/123/jobs/?auth_token=ABC"
```

python:

```
files = {
    'data_file': open('my_audio_file.mp3', 'rb'),
    'model': 'en-US',
    'notification': 'callback',
    'callback': 'http://your_url.com/transcript_callback'
}
requests.post('https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/123/jobs/?auth_token=ABC', files=files)
```

Comment: It would help if you were more specific on the error.

Comment: @RobertB It's just an error from the API.  `b'{\n  "code": 400, \n  "error": "No language selected"\n}'`

Answer (score 0):

I determined the error was related to the `requests` library.  Using version `2.11.1` fixes this issue.

Also the correct form-data looks like:

```
files = {
    'data_file': open('my_audio_file.mp3', 'rb'),
    'model': ('', 'en-US'),
    'notification': ('', 'callback'),
    'callback': ('', 'http://your_url.com/transcript_callback')
}
```